# Default styling classes for a password/username input form on bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So i am making a php login page. I have the login application finished but all i need are a list of classes that will style my login form the way i want it.

Picture of the login form now - https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VjGd.png

I need to style it so it is centered on the screen and will also not take the whole width.

I want it to look like this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/21ji9.png

Now i need it centered on the screen. Note im not adding in the Email input and text box. Only my Username and Password input. All i need is styles.

For a live version please visit gippixservers.com/zAdmin/admindashboard

Code -
    ">

```
<div class = "form-group">
<label for="txtUsername" class = "col-lg-2 control-label">Username:</label> 

<div class = "col-lg-10">
                    <input class = "form-control input-block-level" type="text" title="Enter your Username" name="txtUsername" placeholder = "Username" />
</div>

</div>

<div class = "form-group">
<label for="txtPassword" class = "col-lg-2 control-label">Password:</label> 

<div class = "col-lg-10">
<input class = "form-control input-block-level" type="password" title="Enter your     password" name="txtPassword" placeholder = "Password" />
</div>

</div>

<div class = "form-control">
<input class = "btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="Submit" value = "Login"></input>
</div> 

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap uses a grid system to place elements:

[image: Bootstrap grid]

There are 12 grids you can have on one row. I have used `col-*-offset` in the code, this will leave space in the beginning. So what I'm basically doing is:

> form class="form-horizontal **col-md-offset-4 col-md-4**" name="form"
>   method="post" action="/zAdmin/admindashboard.php"

This means, leave grid of 4 length before the form, and set the form to be of grid 4 length thus your form gets centered. [the leftover space on right is 4, all together in total making it 12]

Few changes made near your login button too. Use the class `pull-right` to position elements to the right side.

Also, **remove this**:

```
#gippix-adminControl {
width: 50%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This is already done with the classes I mentioned above.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/agLnX/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

I think your asking to make the live version smaller and centered ?

You need to add the following to your form tag. OR wrap your form in a div.

```
width: 50%; /* or whatever width you see fit */
margin: 0 auto;
```

Alternatively, You can view all bootstraps predefined form display options -   [getbootstrap.com/css/#forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms)

Or on your div `<div id="gippix-adminControl" ... inputs... </div>`
Just adjust your css to

```
#gippix-adminControl input{
   width: blah;
   max-width: blah;
   min-width: blah;
}
```

To move your login button to the right simply set your

```
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login">
```

to `float: right;` either in your css sheet or inline.

Comment: With bootstrap 3 being a mobile-first framework, I would not prefer to set the width like that, because you'd have to set it to a bigger value for mobile with a media query.

Comment: Thx a bunch :D Theres still one problem. How do i position the Login button so its here - http://i.imgur.com/Xc6rL1H.png

Comment: I answered that in my post =)

Answer (score 0):

You can put a max-width to your .gippix-adminControl css class and go from there.

```
.container{max-width: 500px;}
```

You can also remove the div around your button , that will get rid of the unintended border. Then put a float: right on the button and you'll have yourself a good looking login form !

you can also make a .loginbutton-right css class like this :

```
.loginbutton-right{float: right;}
```

and add that class to your button !

It results in this :

[image: http://i58.tinypic.com/8wlc1k.png]